# Relationship of exterior points of two sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A^e$ denote the exterior points of A. Suppose that $A\subseteq B$, then $A^e \supseteq B^e$.

I'm learning topology by myself and not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Look at $x \in B^e,$ then there exist a neighborhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $B$. That would implies that the nbhd is disjoint from $A$ since $A \subseteq B$

Comment: To elaborate on @MaximeScott: Note that if $A\subseteq B$ then $X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the whole space. Now the complement $(B^e)^C=\overline{B}$ and similarly $(A^e)^C=\overline{A}$. Since $A\subseteq B$, we have $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ and hence $X\setminus \overline{B} \subseteq X\setminus \overline{A} \Rightarrow X\setminus(B^e)^C \subseteq X\setminus(A^e)^C \Rightarrow B^e \subseteq A^e$.